# Is this nested template base class ambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, crtp, template-argument-deduction

This code used to compile in Clang 3.8, and still compiles in VS 2017, but started emitting an error in Clang 3.9.

```
template <typename D, typename ... I>
struct impl : I ...
{};

template <typename D, typename ... I>
void f(impl<D, I...> const&)
{}

struct A : impl<A> {};
struct B : impl<B, A> {};

int main()
{
    f(A());
    f(B()); // Error
}
```

Clang 3.9 says

```
<source>:15:5: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
    f(B());
    ^
<source>:6:6: note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction
void f(impl<D, I...> const&)
     ^
```

All three compilers in action:
https://godbolt.org/g/OKFpPl

I want `f(A())` to deduce `D = A, I... = <>` and `f(B())` to deduce `D = B, I... = A`, which is then deducible as an instance of `impl`. My end goal is to detect type in `impl`'s parameter pack that are themselves instances of `impl`. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: the easiest workaround I found: https://wandbox.org/permlink/DxJmdi4YV0F4mPT7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure but...

Your `B` class inherit from `impl<B, A>` that inherit from `impl<A>`.

So `B` inherit from a couples of different `impl<D, I...>` base classes, so the type deduction is ambigous (`D == B` and `I... == <A>` or `D == A` and `I... == <>`).

So I think that clang 3.8 is wrong and that 3.9 is right.

> My end goal is to detect type in impl's parameter pack that are themselves instances of impl. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Yes, you're doing it in the wrong way (I think).

Comment: Yeah, I have a suspicion that difference between Clang 3.8 and 3.9 is conformance tightening. But my standardese isn't strong enough to be totally sure.

Also, since this is all CRTP anyway, I remembered that in my exact situation, I know the first template parameter, which allows me to disambiguate. But I'm still curious about the core language question. :) For instance, one of those type deductions requires a "conversion to base" to match, while the other doesn't. Wouldn't the one be a better match?

Comment: @RyanShepherd - unfortunately, my standardese is too weak to reaspond to your questions. And I've tryed "to detect type in impl's parameter pack that are themselves instances of impl" but I've found the problem too complicated. Regarding the "conversion to base", if you refer to the call to the `f()` function, both call require a conversion to base; the problem is that the second one obtain a conversion to two different bases.